# MVC MultiSelectList or Input loop only returns first value to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, loops, model-view-controller, multi-select

I have a controller that uses a ViewBag to bring the data into the view.

```
var _021CheckBox = dc.OptionsTbls.Where(a => a.Question_ID == 21).ToList();
ViewBag.CheckBoxfacilities = new SelectList(_021CheckBox, "ID", "QOption").ToList();
```

Then i have the View that's supposed to submit a string back to the controller but it only sends the first selected item. I even tried Javascript to combine the two but that did not work either. here's my view (both listboxfor and loop

//Loop

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.CheckBoxfacilities.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model._021CheckBox[i], new { @id = "_021CheckBox" })
            <input name="_021CheckBox" type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.CheckBoxfacilities[i].Text" id="@ViewBag.CheckBoxfacilities[i].Value" /> @ViewBag.CheckBoxfacilities[i].Text <br />

        }
```

// listboxfor

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m._021CheckBox, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.CheckBoxfacilities, "Value", "Text"), new { @Multiple = "multiple" })
```

//JavaScript that appends the value

```
    <script>
    
        var Values = [];
        $('input[name=_021CheckBox]').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                Values.push($(this).val() + ";");
            }
            else {
                Values.pop(this);
    
            }
            $('#_021CheckBox').val(Values).appendTo('form');
            document.getElementById("_021CheckBox").value = Values;

        });
</script>
```

here is my Model. I think maybe this is where i'm messing up

```
    [Table("TBLMajorQuestions")]
    public partial class TBLMajorQuestion
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string _021CheckBox { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i was trying to fit a square peg into a circle. The easiest thing to do is editvmy column from `_021CheckBox` to `_021aCheckBox` and to add two more columns into my table. `_021bCheckBox` and `_021cCheckBox`. Now i change them from strings to bits and update my model accordingly.

In the view, i took out all the extra javascript and did `@html.CheckBoxFor(m => m._021aCheckBox)`. Done! Did the same for the other two checkboxes.